# Working with Scotty and Sqlite and having some trouble with the Monads

Tags: sqlite, haskell, functional-programming, monads, scotty

Hi I a pretty new to Haskell and I have been working on a small web application with Scotty and Sqlite.

I am having trouble performing Sqlite operations inside the Scotty Actions.
I kind of understanding the two libraries when used in isolation.

Here is the MVP of my code

```
-- imports ...

routes :: ScottyM ()
routes = do 
    post "data/:id" $ do
        id <- param "id"
        -- HERE IS WHERE I GET CONFUSED
        -- This is what I want to do
        db <- open "store.db"
        exec db "INSERT INTO Store (id, value) VALUES (" <> id <> ", 'Test Value');" -- I know there is SQL Injection here I will learn about parameterized queries in haskell next
        close db
        -- END THE PART I AM CONFUSED BY
        text $ "created a record with " <> id <> " id."

main :: IO()
    scotty 3000 routes
```

So as you can see I am still stuck thinking too imperatively.
I know the type of post is ActionM () -> ScottyM ()
and I know the type of close db is IO ()

So what I think I need is a composite function that goes 
ActionM () -> IO () -> ScottyM ()
I am just not sure how to write this.

Is this on the right track?

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monads stack (technically, Monad Transformers stack).  Which means that in some advanced monads it is possible to do thing with more basic monads further down the stack.

The `lift` function will take a function from one level down the stack and "lift" it into the current one.  the `liftIO` function will take a generic IO function and lift it into the current context.  (IO, if it is included, is always the bottom of the Monad Transformer stack)

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) and the [Haskell Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) both have good chapters on Monad Transformers.

Comment: Awesome thank you I did not know these existed! Just more to learn.